# can a lambda invoke another lambda, and then exit before child lambda completes?

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I have two AWS lambdas written in go.  One lambda invokes the other like this:

```
payload, err := json.Marshal(request)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("ERROR: could not marshal request [%v] into model.ChildLambdaRequest - %v\n", request, err)
    return false
}

log.Printf("--- debug sending payload: %s", payload)

// Invoke Child

result, err := client.Invoke(&lambda.InvokeInput{
    FunctionName: aws.String(lambdaName),
    Payload:      payload,
})
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("ERROR: could not invoke Lambda function client [%v] - %v\n", lambdaName, err)
    return false
}
```

The child lambda completes like this:

```
return model.EventResponse{Success: true}, nil
```

I know this is doing two things: 1.) it's finishing the execution and 2.) it's returning a value.  Is there any way to separate these two actions, so that I can return a value at the top, but complete execution at a later time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to pass `InvocationType: "Event"` to the `Invoke` call, documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/lambda/#InvokeInput). The default invocation type is `RequestResponse` which waits for the response from the invoked Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with [Destinations in Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/).

Although I would check out [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/), which gives you this functionality together with built-in retries and error handling.
It works with existing Lambda functions and has a pretty easy to use interface.

Last option that could work, you send a message from the first function to an SQS Queue,
and your second lambda is triggered by the SQS Queue. This also gives you retry capabilities.